# CSS3 rotate3D cross-browser issue

Tags: css

So i have this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aA9Rm/1/ . It works just fine in firefox, but i have some issues with it in chrome, and i can't understand why. In firefox if i move the mouse after the hover in the workhover container it works fine, doesn't do anything, but in chrome if i try to click or move an inch, it starts to move (shake) and I don't want that.

I use 3D rotations, from CSS3,

```
-moz-transform: rotateY(-90deg);;
-webkit-transform:rotateY(-90deg);
transform:rotateY(-90deg);
```

Solutions anyone?

Comment: Any chance your chrome://gpu says that 3D CSS is unavailable?

Comment: 3D CSS: Hardware accelerated

Comment: It works, but it not very well, if i move the mouse on the second face, after the rotation, it moves a little, is not fixed like in firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you encounter the same bug from this question :
[CSS Flip Transition Between Two <div>'s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16982499/css-flip-transition-between-two-divs/16984368#comment24535262_16984368)

It looks like a chrome bug where the div you're trying to rotate is rotating a bit too much. I can fix your jsfiddle on Chrome by changing this CSS (see the webkit degree) :

```
.cube:hover{
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(-89.9deg);
    transform:rotateY(-90deg);
}
```

It's quite *hacky* but I never found any clean solution.
You can also use `pointer-events: none;` property in some way to make it works.