# CSS 3D-cube rotates to side, parent elements wrongly above surface when rotating 90deg, but not when 89.9deg

Tags: css, google-chrome, transform

In Chrome, I'm trying to rotate a cube, but after that the side suddenly is not intractable, and parent elements seem to take precedence.
However, when I make that element `pointer-events: none`, the `body` tag is the first element, so for some reason after rotating `90deg` it looses its interaction.

*However*, when I only rotate it `89.9deg`, there's no problem and I can interact with the elements on the side, I tried fiddling with `translateZ` but that doesn't help.

I recreated it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/TrySpace/GxJLV/

**And**, in firefox it works fine...

Anyone familiar with this bug/difference and how to fix it?

-
It seems that the container element I'm rotating looses all its interactions because that container element is a flat surface in the inspector, which holds the 3d elements, thus no interactions on a plane that is viewed from the side?

Update: http://jsfiddle.net/TrySpace/GxJLV/2/ (89.9 degrees still works...)

Comment: It seems to be a bug with Chrome, i encounter it multiple time with 3D. There are no other ways than hacks like `89.9deg` or `pointer-event:none;`. Same issue here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16982499/css-flip-transition-between-two-divs and here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18484875/css3-rotate3d-cross-browser-issue

Comment: What @AurélienGrimpard said is true. It's a rendering bug, there is not much else to say

Comment: Also, you have a lot of unnecessary CSS in your demo. It makes it hard to see what exactly is being applied

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting hit by a combination of rounding errors and Chrome's handling of hit testing (there is at least http://crbug.com/126479 - that bug is not closed and the recently landed patch didn't fix your case AFAICT).

For reference, here's a simplified version of the fiddle with extra html and css removed: http://jsfiddle.net/GxJLV/7/

## Fix, alternative 1

You are specifying

```
.show-right {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -90deg);
    ...
}
```

but if you check the computed style in Developer Tools you'll see that it becoms

```
-webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.00000000000000006123233995736766, 0, 1, 0,
                            0, 1, 0, 0, -1,
                            0, 0.00000000000000006123233995736766, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
```

This results in the rotated div and button to be underneath the body in 3d z order. If you replace the `rotate3d` with

```
.show-right {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    ...
}
```

hit testing will work (see http://jsfiddle.net/GxJLV/3/ against original, http://jsfiddle.net/GxJLV/10/ against the simplified version).

## Fix, alternative 2

(Why this works is not clear to me, but [other people are doing it as well](https://github.com/bartaz/impress.js/issues/128#issuecomment-15950169).)

Set `(-webkit-)perspective` on the parent of the rotated element:

```
.view {
    -webkit-perspective: 100000px;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/GxJLV/4/ (original, http://jsfiddle.net/GxJLV/8/ simplified)

This will cause some flicker on the button though.

Comment: While it's ultimately still really a bug, +500 for your effort, thanks! Sorry for the messy fiddle, but I had been working on it for at least an hour, when I decided to check another browser...